# Keep CakePHP's layout but modify it

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

Is there a way to modify CakePHP's default layout without needing to make my own? I am in the process of developing the back-end but would like to have something easy to looking at in the front-end for testing.

I know I need to make `default.ctp` in `views/layout` but but I don't want to make a layout from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the `default.ctp` layout from `cake/libs/views/layouts/` into `app/views/layouts/` and modify it as needed.